# How to reserve the Training Progress Panel after training

Tags: neural-networks

After the network train, the *Training Progress Panel* will disappear in *MMA*.But the panel always give a lot of information about the trained result. Such as this `net`

```
net = LinearLayer[];
trained = NetTrain[net, {1 -> 1.9, 2 -> 4.1, 3 -> 6.0, 4 -> 8.1}]
```

I hope the Training Progress Panel don't disapear after the training. Is possible?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to keep the panel, but you can store the data shown in the panel using something like `TrainingProgressReporting -> ((t = <|KeyValueMap[# -> #2 &]@#|>) &)` (this stores the data in `t`) and build a table yourself. (The explicit rebuilding is necessary to for the values of the association to evaluate)

Comment: This will work too but won't help as values don't exist after the training is finished: `Unprotect@PrintTemporary;
Block[{PrintTemporary = Print},
 trained = NetTrain[net, {1 -> 1.9, 2 -> 4.1, 3 -> 6.0, 4 -> 8.1}]
 ]
Protect@PrintTemporary`

Comment: @Kuba Almost man..Just little flaw...Could we take a picture for the panel after finish the train?

Comment: a lot of information? what information

Comment: @partida Such as it is overfit not not, such as the trained time, I mean those information in that panel~

Comment: This doesn't answer your question for `NetTrain`, but calling `PredictorInformation` on the returned `PredictorFunction` from `Predict` does give all the information that's in the training progress panel.

Answer (score 3):

I give you some hint,then you can prettify it.

```
data = Flatten@
Table[{x, y} -> x*y, {x, -1, 1, .005}, {y, -1, 1, .005}];
epochs = 2;
batchSize = 1024;
batchsPerEpochs = Floor[Length[data]/batchSize];
net = NetChain[{32, Tanh, 1}];
{trained, info} = {First@#, Rest@#} &@
NetTrain[net, data, Automatic(*loss function*), 
        {"TrainedNet", "LossEvolutionPlot", "LastRoundLoss", 
         "LastValidationLoss", "MeanBatchesPerSecond", 
         "MeanInputsPerSecond", "TotalTrainingTime"}, 
         BatchSize -> batchSize, 
         MaxTrainingRounds -> Round[epochs*Length[data]*0.9/batchSize], 
         ValidationSet -> Scaled[0.1]];
```

[image]

```
Column[Join[{"BatchSize:" <> ToString@batchSize, 
             "rounds:" <> ToString@epochs, 
             Sequence @@ 
                Thread[{"LossEvolutionPlot", "LastRoundLoss", 
                        "LastValidationLoss", "MeanBatchesPerSecond", 
                        "MeanInputsPerSecond", "TotalTrainingTime"} -> info]}]]
```

[image]

All of the properties list here

[image]